# How to combine multiple groupby aggregations with calculated column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Disclaimer: I'm a doctor with no formal training tasked with building a report that looks at how many patients are meeting therapy goals, and I need to break this down by facility and clinic. I can get the denominator (total cases by facility and clinic) and the numerator (total cases meeting therapy goals), but I can't figure out how to display both of those in a groupby along with a column showing the percent meeting goals (num / denom).

Sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
                   ['anxiety','PTSD','PTSD','anxiety','PTSD','depression','anxiety','anxiety','PTSD','anxiety','anxiety','anxiety','depression','depression','PTSD'],
                   [False,False,False,True,True,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],
                   ['120C','120C','120C','120C','120C','120C','120C','120C','120C','120C','375C','375C','375C','375C','375C'],
                   ['BH-PSYL','BH-PSYL','BH-YUKON','BH-DENALI','BH-YUKON','BH-DENALI','BH-CFS','BH-CFS','BH-CFS','BH-CFS','BH-HTHPSY','BH-HTHPSY','BH-BSS','BH-HTHPSY','BH-BSS']]).T
df.columns = ['Patient ID','DX Category','Met Goal','Facility','Clinic']
```

This gives the denominator:

`df.groupby(['Facility', 'Clinic']).count()[['Met Goal']]`

This gives the numerator:

`df[df['Met Goal'] == True].groupby(['Facility', 'Clinic']).count()[['Met Goal']]`

The final result should show (made-up numbers):

```
Facility | Clinic   | Met Goal | Cases | Percent
120C
         | BH-PSYL  |     1    |   4   |  25%
         | BH-YUKON |     2    |   6   |  33%
375C     
         | BH-CFS   |     0    |   1   |   0%
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done most of the work, but to get the final output, you can do:

```
#first calculate at once the numerator and denominator in the same dataframe
df_final = df.groupby(['Facility', 'Clinic']).agg({'Met Goal':['sum', 'count']})
#then change the name of the columns
df_final.columns = ['Met Goal','Cases']
#finally calaulate the percent
df_final['Percent'] = df_final['Met Goal']/df_final['Cases']
```

and you get:

```
print (df_final)
                    Met Goal  Cases  Percent
Facility Clinic                             
120C     BH-CFS            1      4     0.25
         BH-DENALI         1      2     0.50
         BH-PSYL           0      2     0.00
         BH-YUKON          1      2     0.50
375C     BH-BSS            0      2     0.00
         BH-HTHPSY         0      3     0.00
```

Comment: F/U question - if I add a third column to the groupby, [it no longer interprets True / False correctly] (https://imgur.com/a/0vRlUKI). Does this method only work when two columns are used?

Comment: Adding ```df_final['Met Goal'] = df_final['Met Goal'].astype(int)``` after renaming the columns appears to fix it, though I still don't understand why it worked without it for two columns but not three. *shrug*

Comment: @pediatrictactic what I can tell from your picture is that the `sum` does not transform the boolean `True/False` to `int` if there is only one value in the group. It is not directly because of a third column in the groupby, but here it is because your dataset is too small. It is an interesting result, I'll have a look at it later !! but your way of fixing it with `astype` is a good solution :)

Comment: @pediatrictactic apparently it is a [known issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7001) for a while but it has not been fixed yet. So I guess using `astype` is a safe work around for your need :)